# Wordpress - Use of SQL code in page edit

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I have a problem. I have below code which works fine, but when I add this code into page through page edit, `database connection` does not work.

See below code:

```
    <?php
    $db = mysql_connect('localhost', 'user', 'password')
    or die ('Neda sa pripojit');
mysql_select_db('database', $db);
$email = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['email']);
$request = "SELECT ID
            FROM wpt2_users
            WHERE user_email='$email'";
$result = mysql_query($request, $db) or die(mysql_error($db));
$riadok = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
extract($riadok);

$request2 = "SELECT meta_value
            FROM wpt2_usermeta
            WHERE meta_key = 'rpr_kd'
            AND user_id='$ID'";
$result2 = mysql_query($request2, $db) or die(mysql_error($db));

$riadok2 = mysql_fetch_assoc($vysledky2);
extract($riadok2);

if (isset($_GET['kod']) && $_GET['kod'] == $meta_value)
{
echo 'You have access!';
echo do_shortcode('[ngg_uploader id=1]');
  }
else
  {
echo 'You do not have access!';
  }
?>
```

I downloaded plugin `Exec-PHP`, which works fine and allow to use PHP code in page editor. I know that in WordPress I should rewrite that code somehow, but I do not know how should it be written.

Could you help me?
Thank you.

Comment: Please update your question to explain something. Are you trying to connect to the same MySQL database that WordPress uses? If so, what's up with your call to `mysql_connect()`?

Comment: First of all, Wordpress offers a complete DB abstraction layer: codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb Since you are performing this within the Wordpress framework it would be better to stick with the provided tools, which sanitize input and offer any additional checks your might also need Secondly it would be wise to move your code into a function and place it either inside a plugin or inside your theme in the functions.php file. Throwing pure PHP code inside pages adds just headaches and possible security breaches all over your code.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try putting that code into a custom template file, where it would run the code normally without the use of a plugin.

Comment: And would it be possible to use shortcode 
"echo do_shortcode('[ngg_uploader id=1]');"  ?